# The same brace thickness in scalebox

Tags: math-mode, scalebox

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\scalebox{0.5}[1]{$\displaystyle
\left\{\scalebox{2}[1]{$\displaystyle\begin{array}{ll}
P=P(r_+,M)\\
T=T(r_+,P(r_+,M)),
\end{array}$}\right.$}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\scalebox{0.5}[1]{$\displaystyle
\left\{\scalebox{2}[1]{$\displaystyle\begin{array}{ll}
\bigg(\displaystyle\frac{\partial P}{\partial V}\bigg)_{T,Q_e}\bigg|_{V_c,T_c}=0\\
\bigg(\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2P}{\partial V^2}\bigg)_{T,Q_e}\bigg|_{V_c,T_c}=0.
\end{array}$}\right.$}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A+\bigg(\bigg(\bigg(\frac{B}{C}+\frac{B}{C}\bigg)\bigg)\bigg)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I'd like to do the brace thickness in `(1)` like in `(2)`. Also, maybe there is some better way to represent such formulas `(1)-(3)`.

Comment: I just don't like thick standard brackets.

Comment: As a rule, using `\scalebox` is a bad idea almost every time, since it messes badly with fonts (which may be related to your problem). So can you first explain why you used `\scalebox` in the first place? This looks like a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Miyase: thanks. My problem is that I don't like thick standard braces and I'd like to do them much thinner and the same thickness for `1` and `2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution with the `empheq` package?

```
     \documentclass[14pt]{extarticle}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{empheq}
    \usepackage{diffcoeff}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    P & =P(r_+,M)\\
    T & =T(r_+,P(r_+,M)),
    \end{aligned}
    \end{empheq}
    \begin{empheq}[left=\enspace \empheqlbrace]{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    \biggl(\diffp{P}{V}[T,Q_e]\biggm|_{V_c,T_c} & =0\\
    \bigg(\diffp[2]{P}{V}[T,Q_e]\biggm|_{V_c,T_c} & =0.
    \end{aligned}
    \end{empheq}
    \begin{equation}
    \quad A+\biggl(\biggl(\biggl(\frac{B}{C}+\frac{B}{C}\biggr)\biggr)\biggr)
    \end{equation}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: thanks for warning me. I must say I had several things in mind when I posted. It's fixed now.

Comment: @Bernard: thanks, I've not known about `\diffp`, and a horizontal shift between the equations in `2` is better in your solution. My main desire was to make braces much thinner and the same thickness for `1` and `2`.

Comment: @misha.physics: for thinner braces, unfortunately, the only sensible way I know  to obtain it would be to use a math font which is thinner by design. . You may try to have a look at the LaTeX Font Catalogue.

Comment: Now it seems to me, that the standard brace thickness is good, so let it be.